# Running JDK 1.5 on Eclipse Kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I've code that has to run on JDK 1.5
Plus i need some plugins which has not stopped working for Juno...

How do i hack around to make my Kepler run on 1.5 JDK and not JDK 1.6. This way i'll have my required plugins and my code.

It might be not possible but just wanted to check with community did anyone found similar scenario and got hack around it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can choose which JDK version you want to use when creating new project. If I understood your question right?

Comment: Yes.. I Figure in same direction. Thanks a ton.